# How to pass parameters in xmlhttp (vba)

Tags: vba, woocommerce, parameters, xmlhttprequest

I have a program that I would like to integrate with WooCommerce.  I am running into an issue when attempting to add a new product.  Specifically the category and image fields.  The following code works properly:  (I changed to put instead of post so I would update the same product rather than continuing to add incomplete items)

```
myurl = "https://url.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?sku=" & UPC & "&name=" & title & "&regular_price=" & price &consumer_key=" & rs!woocomkey & "&consumer_secret=" & rs!woocomsecret
xmlhttp.Open "put", myurl, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "accept", "application/json"
xmlhttp.send
```

It works but sets the category to id 174 uncategorized

when I try to add the addition parts below and mess with the formatting slightly I either get the same result or the error message Below it

```
myurl = "https://url.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?sku=" & UPC & "&name=" & title & "&regular_price=" & price & "&categories=[{id=" & cat2 & "}]&images=[{src=http://url.com/pos/default.jpg}]&consumer_key=" & rs!woocomkey & "&consumer_secret=" & rs!woocomsecret

{"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Invalid parameter(s): categories","data":    {"status":400,"params":{"categories":"categories[0] is not of type object."}}}
```

I believe the issue is that I don't know the proper syntax when there is a subcategory.  Here is the related api document from Woocommerce.  I don't know PHP, Curl or the other options they list.

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products \
-u consumer_key:consumer_secret \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
"name": "Premium Quality",
"type": "simple",
"regular_price": "21.99",
"description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac    turpisegestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
"short_description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
"categories": [
{
  "id": 9
},
{
  "id": 14
}
],
"images": [
{
  "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg"
},
{
  "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg"
}
]
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This part looks wrong  `"&regular_price=" & price &consumer_key=" & rs!woocomkey &`

Comment: You might be better off posting/putting your data in json format in the request body than in the querystring.

Comment: See here for a useful library:  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

Comment: I will look at the library you sent...The part you said looks wrong actually work as the price is updated and the consumer key is used to authenticate....I restructured to put the category part in the body...like

Comment: ```xmlhttp.send ("categories[id]=" & cat2 & ") with the image and category section removed from myurl section but still no success...did get a different error message though that said categories is not of type array

Comment: you are correct, I see the error you were references...sorry it was correct in my code, I just had difficulties putting my code into the brackets to show it was code on the site.  It was my first post...sorry

Comment: I would still look into using JSON if you can - it will be cleaner and the JSON api examples are usually easier to follow.

Comment: I took your advice and recoded as JSON.  Here is the woocommerce example:

Comment: `curl -X PUT https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/794 \
    -u consumer_key:consumer_secret \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
  "regular_price": "24.54"
}' then I added xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json" and xmlhttp.send ("c:/test/woocommerce5.json") '''''''''''my json file is as follows...………….{
"regular_price": "24.54"
} I get the following error message.....{"code":"rest_invalid_json","message":"Invalid JSON body passed.","data":{"status":400,"json_error_code":4,"json_error_message":"Syntax error"}}

Comment: You can edit that into your question - not readable in a comment.

Comment: Got it sorted out...just created the json data and set application/json...in case anyone else needs assistance...xmlhttp.send ("{" & Chr(34) & "name" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & title & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "sku" & Chr(34) & _
        ": " & Chr(34) & UPC & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "regular_price" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & price & Chr(34) & "," _
        & Chr(34) & "categories" & Chr(34) & ": [{" & Chr(34) & "id" & Chr(34) & ": " & cat2 & "}]}")